# How to enable RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE like feature in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, serial-port

I'm a developing a Windows application for communication with meter devices over serial modems. Some of the devices using half duplex communication. For that reason I'm setting the Windows RtsControl parameter to RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE, which enables an automatic switch of the RTS line state.

Now I want to port this application to Linux. Is there an function to enable an equivalent feature to the RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE parameter on a Linux OS?

If there is no such function, does a workaround exist to enable a similar behavior?

Comment: Are you certain that the serial modems implement RTS/CTS flow control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're in user space - so you'll probably end up using an [IOCTL](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html). If you're moving from Windows to Linux for serial control I recommend reading [The POSIX Serial Programing Guide](http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html#listing6). The link I give is an example for setting serial values with an IOCTL, you would need to change it to use TIOCM_RTS, TIOCM_CTS, but it gives the right idea.